# is it possible to allow only root user to create Environment variable?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

We know , Linux world right now watching on Bash bug with environment variables.

So , I just want to know If we can make something like only root user can create environment variables and all other applications,services and users cant & All applications,users & services in system have to use only defined variables by root.

so can we make this &  If yes please tell me how . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

But the Environment Variables that the user creates (or overwrites the System Environment Variables) is only temporary (they disappear when the user logs off). Also, only the user can use these variables.